# 'Assigned' id in gorm configuration doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a grails 4 app that has 2 configured datasources : 'back', and 'front'.
For the back db, I have a 'identity' id generator. 
For the front db, I have a 'assigned' id generator, as I want the front to be a perfect replica of the back, including ids.

So I have the following configuration in application.groovy file :

```
grails.gorm.front.mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned'
}

grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    id generator: 'identity'
}
```

I create my objects in the back db, the ids are correctly generated with
`myObject.save()` But when I want to save my replicated objects in the front with `myObject.front.save()`, the 'assigned' id configuration is ignored, and looking at the hibernate queries log, I find that they are generated without the id column.

Has anyone any idea about how to solve this ? Is my configuration ok ?

Thanks !